# Open LWC Component upon clicking Bar Chart data-point

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, lightning-components, chartjs

My requirement is to open different LWC Component upon clicking different Bar Chart data-point.

I am using ChartJS library to achieve this.

[image]

Here is the code I have tried to implement ---

I am using onclick event in options in JS.

**HTML**

```
<template if:true={showgraph }>
   <div style="width: 100%;">
      <canvas class="stepped" style="display: block;margin-top: -25px;
       width: 1235px;height: 400px;">
      </canvas>
   </div>
</template>

<template if:true={showComponentOnClick }>
   <div style="width: 100%;">
      <c-hello-world></c-hello-world>
   </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import rexourceContainer from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/Resources"; 

export default class chart extends LightningElement {

    @track showgraph = true;
    @track showComponentOnClick = false;

 chartjs = rexourceContainer + "/js/chart.js";
 connectedCallback() {

if (this.chartjsInitialized) {
          return;
        }
        this.chartjsInitialized = true;
        Promise.all([
          loadScript(this, this.utilJs),
          loadScript(this, this.chartjs)

        ])
          .then(() => { 

        this.generateSteppedChart();

})
          .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
          });  
      }
      errorCallback(error) {
        this.error = error;
      }

         graphClickEvent(){
            window.console.log("In graph click");
            this.showgraph = false;
            this.showComponentOnClick = true;
            window.console.log(this.showgraph);
            window.console.log(this.showComponentOnClick);
    } 

 generateSteppedChart() {
        var barChartData = {
            labels: ["Jan","Feb","March","April","May","Jun","July","August","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Total Amount"],
            datasets: [

            {
                label: "Credit",
                backgroundColor: "#6B8A70",


                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50]
              },
              {
                label: "Debit",
                backgroundColor: "#F5A623",


                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30,20.30]
              },
            ]
          };

          var dataSet = {
            type: "bar",
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
              legend:{
                display:true,
                position:"top",
                labels: {
                  boxWidth:20
              }

              },tooltips:{enabled:true},
              cutoutPercentage: 75,
              responsive: true,
              title: {
                display: true,
               // text: "DPD Assessment"
              },
              scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMax: 90
                  },
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Amount ( in INR Lakhs)'
                  }
                }],
                xAxes: [{

                    barPercentage: 0.5,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                    },

                }]
              },
            onClick: graphClickEvent
            }
          };
          const ctx = this.template.querySelector("canvas.stepped").getContext("2d");
          this.steppedChart = new window.Chart(ctx, dataSet);


        }

      }
```

Comment: This modal you want to open, will be the same no matter where you click on the chart?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo No, on each datapoint, different LWC shlould get opened.

Answer (score 0):

@MohitKulkarni, you need to fire an event using pubsub on click of the bar and pass the parameters which are required to render the LWC data. Also you need to register that event in connected call back of the LWC.

From Bar : `fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'timelineFocus', {start: key, period: this.chartPeriod});`

In LWC : `connectedCallback() {
        // subscribe to searchKeyChange event
        registerListener('timelineFocus', this.handleSearchKeyChange, this);
    }`

Here timelineFocus is the event sent out on bar click which is listened in the LWC i want to render. On getting the event handleSearchKeyChange is used to manipulate and render LWC functionality.